# Installing PHP Composer on Yocto/Arm Beaglebone

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, beagleboneblack, yocto

We have a custom SOM based on the Beaglebone. It has Apache2 and PHP 7 running on the Pyro branch of the Poky project.

PHP 7 runs just fine in Apache, however, I am trying to get PHP composer to run on the board with little success.

In following the [composer install instructions](https://getcomposer.org/download/), it fails with an error message that I do not have ssl enabled in php:

```
root@board-1:~# php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
PHP Warning:  copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning:  copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
```

This is my php_7.%.bbappend:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-php = " apache2 " 

EXTRA_OECONF = "--enable-mbstring \
                --enable-wddx \
                --enable-fpm \
                --enable-zip \
                --with-libdir=${baselib} \
                --with-gettext=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                --with-zlib=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                --with-openssl=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
                --with-iconv=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.. \
                --with-mcrypt=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
                --with-bz2=${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${exec_prefix} \
                --with-config-file-path=${sysconfdir}/php/apache2-php${PHP_MAJOR_VERSION} \
                ${@base_conditional('SITEINFO_ENDIANNESS', 'le', 'ac_cv_c_bigendian_php=no', 'ac_cv_c_bigendian_php=yes', d)} \
                ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'pam', '', 'ac_cv_lib_pam_pam_start=no', d)} \
                ${COMMON_EXTRA_OECONF} \
"
```

As you can see, I am compiling with SSL. Is there something I am missing here? I can't seem to get composer to build on this ARM (TI AM335x) device and cannot seem to find instructions on how to do so.

Comment: same problem here!

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: @BernardoRodrigues, I have posted my answer below as it may be helpful for you and others. It is not a perfect solution, but it is a good solution for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

After much struggle, the answer is not too hard. But it is different than the official composer instructions.

First, I simply include the composer.phar file (from their website) in with my build.

Then I modified my composer.json to look like this (I have removed some information, but look at the "config" section).

```
{
    "name" : "com.something.whatever",
    "type" : "project",
    "authors" : [{
            ...
        }
    ],
    "config" : {
        "preferred-install" : "dist",
        "disable-tls" : true,
        "secure-http" : false
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "something\\" : "classes/something"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, composer does not update over ssl. So depending on your threat model, this may be an issue. For our project, it does not matter.